# .Net 6 Console application TLS 'HandshakeFailure'

Tags: c#, .net, scheduled-tasks, tls1.2

I currently have a .net 6 console application that is calling a 3rd party vendor API and I get a Handshake error on invocation of the service. This application is being triggered by Windows task scheduler. When executing the API thru Postman I get a successfully response back from the service.

Here is the Cipher Suites shown when the API is executed from the Windows Task Scheduler :

[image: Cipher Suites from Triggered Task execution of API]

Here is the Cipher Suites shown when API is invoked thru Postman:

[image: Cipher Suites after triggered by Postman]

I've added the following as well to see if it would work, however, no luck:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls
| SecurityProtocolType.Tls11
| SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
| SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
```

Comment: TLS failures can also be caused by network issues.  TLS handshake is the first thing that happens after the TCP/IP socket is opened.  So for instance if your user session uses a web proxy or a VPN, and the task does not, there could be network issues.

Comment: Do not use SSL or TLS 1.1 they are obsolete.  Use Only TLS 1.2 or 1.3.  The crypto algorithms you are using are probably TLS 1.3.  See : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security

Comment: On Net 6 you should be using HttpClient and for that ServicePointManager does nothing. You should rather look at HttpClientHandler.SslProtocols. Are you on something older then Windows 11 and the 3rd Party wants to talk Tls 1.3?